# How to let IDA reload a structure from a C file?

Tags: ida

I manage my structures in C files, the header might look like this:

```
#pragma pack(0)

typedef struct
{
    short important_value;
    char  _A[2]; // unknown
    int   interesting_value;
} STRUCT;
```

I loaded this into IDA via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Now I find out more about the structure, seeing that `_A` contains `short imaginary_value`.

When I try to reload this in IDA via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, nothing happens. When I delete the structure in IDA, parse the C file and re-create the structure, I see the new structure, however all instances of `STRUCT` in the database are deleted.

So the question is, how do I reload the structure without removing all instances from the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the `Local Types` (`View->Open Subviews->Local Types` or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) window and then edit it from there by right clicking and clicking on `edit` on your structure's entry on the list.

Comment: Is there a way to completely remove the types there. Not just #deleted?

Comment: @heinrich5991 Did you find a way to remove the `#deleted` entries?

Comment: @crush Unfortunately I didn't, I also stopped reloading the structures at all because it broke some stuff, like forgetting that variables are of a certain type.